# User custom theme support with rails assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, themes, asset-pipeline, handlebars.js, templating

I have a rails app that allows users to create their own website easily but they share the same page structure.

I plan to switch my classic rails views for a templating language such as liquid or handlebars.

The goal is that my users could upload their own version of templates and css to completely customize the look and feel of their website.

*Example of workflow :*

1. *User upload a theme folder containing Templates and Css files*
2. *Their website automatically uses this new templates and designs*

Is it possible to do that and continue to take advantages of the Rails Assets pipeline?

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

This might be something you can try: http://www.krautcomputing.com/blog/2012/03/27/how-to-compile-custom-sass-stylesheets-dynamically-during-runtime/.

I've used this in a Rails 3.2x project and it works fine, but I'm having difficulties getting it working in a different (somewhat modified Rails 4 project).

It's older article about compiling css on the fly using the Sprockets::StaticCompiler class.